# Time-Series LSTM Model wrong prediction

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, time-series, lstm

I am practicing how to create an LSTM model on a univariate series using this dataset from Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/sumanthvrao/daily-climate-time-series-data

My issue is that I am unable to get an accurate prediction of the temperature and my loss seems to be going all over the place. I have tried multiple methods including

- Ensuring that time series data is stationary
- Changing the time steps
- Changing the hyperparameters
- Using a stacked LSTM model

I am really curious as to what is wrong with my code although I do have a few hypothesis:

- I made an error when preprocessing the data
- I introduced stationarity wrongly
- This dataset requires a multivariate approach

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x  # this line is not required unless you are in a notebook
 
import tensorflow as tf
from numpy import array
from numpy import argmax
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten

# preparing independent and dependent features
def prepare_data(timeseries_data, n_features):
    X, y =[],[]
    for i in range(len(timeseries_data)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_features
        # check if we are beyond the sequence
        if end_ix > len(timeseries_data)-1:
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = timeseries_data[i:end_ix], timeseries_data[end_ix]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)

# preparing independent and dependent features
def prepare_x_input(timeseries_data, n_features):
    x = []
    for i in range(len(timeseries_data)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_features
        # check if we are beyond the sequence
        if end_ix > len(timeseries_data):
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x = timeseries_data[i:end_ix]
        x.append(seq_x)
        x = x[-1:]
        #remove non-stationerity
        #x = np.log(x)
    return np.array(x)

#read data and filter temperature column
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Weather Parameter/DailyDelhiClimateTrain.csv')
df.head()
temp_df = df.pop('meantemp')
plt.plot(temp_df)

#make data stationery
sta_temp_df = np.log(temp_df).diff()
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
plt.plot(sta_temp_df)
print(sta_temp_df)

time_step = 7
x, y = prepare_data(sta_temp_df, time_step)
n_features = 1
x = x.reshape((x.shape[0], x.shape[1], n_features))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(time_step, n_features)))
model.add(LSTM(10))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
 
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.summary()

result = model.fit(x, y, epochs=800)

n_days = 113
pred_temp_df = list(temp_df)
test = sta_temp_df.copy()
sta_temp_df = list(sta_temp_df)
i = 0
 
while(i<n_days):
    x_input = prepare_x_input(sta_temp_df, time_step)
    print(x_input)
    x_input = x_input.reshape((1, time_step, n_features))
    #pass data into model
    yhat = model.predict(x_input, verbose=0)
    yhat.flatten
    print(yhat[0][0])
    sta_temp_df.append(yhat[0][0])
    i = i+1

sta_temp_df[0] = np.log(temp_df[0])
cum_temp_df = np.exp(np.cumsum(sta_temp_df))
print(cum_temp_df)
```

My code is shown above. Would really appreciate if someone can identify what I did wrong here!

Comment: @AkshaySehgal this post would not be [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on CR because it appear that the code is not working correctly. Please familiarize yourself with what is on-topic there before recommending users post there. See ["Which Site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/341145) and ["Code Review or not?"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: `because it appear that the code is not working correctly.` what makes you suggest that? The OP has EXPLICITLY mentioned the code **IS RUNNING** but that they are not able to model the data well with their current architecture. `My issue is that I am unable to get an accurate prediction of the temperature ` Please clarify your comment thanks.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Thanks for the feedback, I will post it on the Code Review section instead

Comment: @AkshaySehgal "code working properly" does not mean "bug-free"; it means "*it produces the desired results*", which here is clearly not the case. Unsurprisingly,  the question was not well-received when [reposted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/254784/lstm-model-for-univariate-time-series-forecast) at CR.

Comment: I am a but confused then @desertnaut. `I want to improve results from my model` is usually the type of questions you find on CR in machine learning tag.. i dont see how this question is different. `my model is underfitting` does not mean `my model has bugs`

Comment: It means that OP needs guidance in what would be better to use as features, how can they update the architecture to improve results etc.

Comment: Here is an example of exactly the same type of question, well recieved on CR. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/253582/using-vae-for-reconstructing-images

Comment: @AkshaySehgal then the CR Meta post [When are Machine Learning questions on-topic?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8781/when-are-machine-learning-questions-on-topic) would suggest that it is not on-topic there.

Comment: @desertnaut, this question is of the type `"My Machine Learning currently has an accuracy of x%, which is pretty good. Can it go even higher"` ... just asked differently

Comment: @AkshaySehgal arguably, a better proxy measure is not how many such questions exist but how many are *actually answered*.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal please read more closely; from the answer in the Meta post I linked above: "*"The accuracy is not good enough" [...] means the code is broken and **not ready for review***" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Such questions often don't work well on CR, we've been examining whether we can even support them. While some would like to, it's often not feasible and goes a bit against the general purpose of the site.

Comment: `If the question is phrased as "The accuracy is not good enough"`.. then it's a problem of phrasing the question?

Comment: @Mast, Code Reviews in the machine learning domain DO involve methods to help the models learn better. I believe that would apply to Stack Exchange CR as well. That's the reason why they are included [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8781/when-are-machine-learning-questions-on-topic) as well

Comment: `"The accuracy is not good enough"` could mean its not good relative to standard benchmarks or its not good to my personal benchmark for the problem. In general the idea conveyed is that unlike non-machine learning questions, ML has a added aspect of model fitting and generalizability which can only be addressed POST a architecture has been designed and implements. That makes it a very solid candidate for CR.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal As a regular there, I can tell you from experience that it simply doesn't work well on the site unless it's an exemplary written question. An ML question that states "I am really curious as to what is wrong with my code" will go over like a lead balloon. Please do not suggest Code Review as an alternative site if it's a bad move.

Comment: @Mast -  `"I am really curious as to what is wrong with my code"` I agree on that. But then its just a problem of how OP phrased it right?... Instead of `My issue is that I am unable to get an accurate prediction of the temperature` if they had phrased it as `How do i improve my prediction accuracy of the temperature to be even better than what it is?`.. this would be a viable question? without ANY changes to the code or the underlying problem?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal No.

Comment: @Mast, could you elaborate then. I dont see the difference between "make accuracy better" (which is encouraged) vs "my accuracy is bad, help" (which apparently is not), since the word `accuracy` is subjective and applies differently to different problems.

Comment: According to your own, super well recieved answer - `So I guess it partly depends on how it's phrased. And I don't like that one bit. This is the major question we should be focussing on,`

Comment: I do understand it's subjective, but being in the field for about 9 years now. I can tell you that reviewing the learning capability of a model is a MAJOR aspect of the Code reviews that I have done over the years and is a standard industry practice. Without it we are only asking "make my model production-ready"

Comment: Thank you for pointing out I need to revisit the phrasing of that answer. I get what's causing the misunderstanding now. If the ML is too slow, that's fine on CR. We can fix that. If the accuracy is too low, that's a grey area. Just because something is done in reviews elsewhere, doesn't mean it makes a good question on the site. It could probably be posted, it might even survive, but if I'd encounter this question in the queue I can see multiple reasons to close it. As you say, "my accuracy is bad, help", is not a question we want on CR.

Comment: Hi @Mast, thanks for this great discussion! I see your points and understand where you are coming from. Let me add my thoughts as part of a question at the right forum (the original post about CR in ML). Do check. https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8781/when-are-machine-learning-questions-on-topic/10614#10614

Comment: We can open this discussion to a larger audience now :), but i do agree with the majority of your points.